# I can’t figure out which word to use to describe fluid matter which never stops changing in shape

Tags: single-word-requests

Which word would you use to describe fluid matter which never stops changing in shape?

Comment: Can you give an example? Fluid **by definition** changes its shape - its shape is *"fluid"*. Also note that the SWR tag requires you to provide a sample sentence where the word would be used - hover your pointer over the tag to read the instruction.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest **turbulent**, [defined](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turbulent) as

> characterized by agitation or tumult

Comment: I would say that «turbulent» means it changes internal shape (turbulence is within the fluid), but if, let's imagine, we are in a weightless environment and some fluid wobbles, then it's «wobbly».

Answer (score 0):

Not just a fluid in the sense of a liquid or gas, but anything that can change its form with facility can possibly be **morphodynamic**, i.e., unsteady of form, changes its shape (morphs) from time to time (dynamic).

The term has been "hijacked" by some branches of science/social-sciences for a different purpose, but management theory and linguistics are two areas that recognize the concept.